# Problem of Points (Fermat's Enumeration: Why does it work?)

Tags: probability

Consider a simple case of the problem of points with players $A$ and $B$. Suppose they play a fair game and the first player who wins six rounds wins a prize. Now suppose that the game is interrupted when player $A$ has won five rounds and player $B$ has won three rounds.

Suppose we want to decide how to divide the stakes. We do this by calculating the probability that $A$ will win the game. Here's how I would think of the solution:

Since $A$ is one round from winning and $B$ is 3 rounds from winning, the maximum amount of remaining rounds is given by $(1+3)-1=3$. Then the sample space of possible outcomes for the next three games are as follows
\begin{align*}
\Omega=\{A, BA, BBA, BBB\}
\end{align*}
where, for example, $BBA$ denotes the event that $B$ wins the first two games and $A$ wins the third. 
Now, we have that the only outcomes that give rise to $A$ winning are elements of the set $\{A, BA, BBA\}$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
P(\{A\})+P(\{BA\})+P(\{BBA\})=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{7}{8}.
\end{align*}
So player $A$ has a $7/8$ chance to win and thus gets a 7:1 split of the stake.

However, Fermat's approach is a bit different. He uses a set of equilikely points. In particular, he would say that the sample space of possible outcomes is
\begin{align*}
    \Omega=\{AAA, AAB, ABA, ABB, BAA,
BAB, BBA, BBB\}.
\end{align*}
Now the only sample points that give rise to $B$ winning the game is the event $\{BBB\}$. Thus, player $A$ wins in $7/8$ of the events, and hence the answer is the same as ours above.

Questions:

1) This is a bit of a historical question maybe, but why was Fermat using equilikely sample points? Was the only way to calculate probabilities in his time to use equilikely sample points?

2) a more interesting question; $\textit{why}$ does this method work? For instance, several of the points in Fermat's sample space will never happen, such as $AAA$, $AAB$, $ABA$, etc.  It seems to me that, even though Fermat included spurious sample points, the solution still works out to the same answer. I've thought about this a bit, but I can't think of why that happens.

Thank you!